# IOS don't show logo in splash screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

I create a SplashPage.cs in my Xamarin App, code:

```
public class SplashPage : ContentPage
    {
        Image splashImage;

        public SplashPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            var sub = new AbsoluteLayout();

            splashImage = new Image
            {
                Source = "logo.png",
                WidthRequest = 100,
                HeightRequest = 100
            };
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(splashImage, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(splashImage, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

            sub.Children.Add(splashImage);

            this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#ffff");
            this.Content = sub;
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await splashImage.ScaleTo(1, 2000);
            await splashImage.ScaleTo(0.9, 1500, Easing.Linear);
            await splashImage.ScaleTo(150, 1200, Easing.Linear);

            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());

        }

    }
```

Then in App.xaml.cs

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SplashPage());
        }
```

Directory in Android is `Resources/drawable/logo.png`
Directory for IOS is `Resources/logo.png`

When I compile app in a android phone splash load correctly, but when I try to use in IOS it just no load my icon, only show empty page. I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,this is often the case when you are using images that are not formatted correctly or are very complex.And I've had similar problems before.
Vector graphics are highly recommended in ios.

I have tested this question, when i use a vector image , it worked properly both in ios and android.

Note: You can try it using the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Main purpose of the splash screen is give some time to load application and its components. In case of `Xamarin.Forms` app, this time is used to load Xamarin runtime.

Now, your splash screen it self is using Xamarin.Forms component `ContentPage`. So it can only be displayed after Xamarin runtime is completely loaded.

Best way is to implement splash screen the native way for iOS and Android.

[Here](https://medium.com/@thesultanster/xamarin-splash-screens-the-right-way-3d206120726d) is a good tutorial about how to implement splash screen natively on iOS and Android.